# Typescript, Webpack, AWS SAM and VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, debugging, webpack

I'm working with a dev team that has chosen the hardest possible configuration to get VSCode debugging with SAM.  They are using webpack, because they *have* to use TSyringe (don't get me started) and after messing with it for a while now I'm stuck.  I can get the debugger to initially hook up to SAM and show index.mjs, but all breakpoints aren't picked up.

In `.aws-sam/build` I have the bundled application file (app.js) and the map file (app.js.map).  Where I'm stuck is how I set up my tasks.json file accordingly.

The project topology looks after the webpack build looks like this:

```
- .aws-sam
  - build
    - MyFunction
        -app.js
        -app.js.map

- src
  - app.ts
```

The app.js map has entries like this:

```
{"version":3,"file":"./.aws-sam/build/MyFunction/app.js","mappings": blah blah blah }
```

This is my current iteration with my launch.json file:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "MyFunction",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 5858,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/src",
      "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
      "outFiles": [
        "${workspaceFolder}/.aws-sam/build/PaymentFunction/**/*.js"
      ],
      "sourceMaps": true
    }
  ]
}
```

Any ideas what I missed?

Answer (score 0):

Ended up figuring it out.  VSCode tasks.json looks like this:

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Attach (PaymentFunction)",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "attach",
      "address": "localhost",
      "port": 5858,
      "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/.aws-sam/build/PaymentFunction",
      "remoteRoot": "/var/task",
      "sourceMaps": true,
      "skipFiles": [
        "/var/runtime/**",
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "sourceMapPathOverrides": {
        "webpack://lambda-apps/./src/*": "${workspaceFolder}/src/*"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```